# Rate us In Android fragment

Tags: button, android-fragments, google-play, rate

I'm trying to rewrite this project using fragments. I'm replacing activities with fragments.

This is XML file :

```
'<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Rate Us" />
```

and this is the Full Source Code java:-

```
'public class MainActivity extends Activity{

Button rate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rate);
    rate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 intent.setData(Uri.parse ("market://details?id=APP ID"));
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}`
```

what is the java right code for use this in a fragment?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You need to use extends Fragment instead of Activity for one. Then you need to replace the `void onCreate` method with `View onCreateView`, which returns a rootView. 

You may use this to help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is done:

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

Button rate;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        rate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        rate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse ("market://details?id=APP ID"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

There is no need to change anything in the xml file.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: could you please accept this question if it has helped you? Otherwise I would be more than happy to help you further.